# sencha touch ios8.1 iframe can't scrolling

Tags: iframe, scroll, sencha-touch, ios8.1

1.sencha touch 2.3.1

2.I Used iframe it works well on IOS7.x

3.When Upgrade to IOS8.1，Iframe can't scrolling

**4.IOS8.1 in safari works well,but when send to home screen,and open it it can't work.**

WHY?is a bug?

my iframe code like this:

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;background:url(resources/images/loading.gif) center center no-repeat; height:500px; overflow: auto;">
<iframe src="/abc.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set fixed height. Does it work?

Also, try to add:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to your frame.

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue with 8.1. I am going through the same. Surprisingly, iframe scroll works fine in chrome but Safari has issues.

http://www.applevis.com/blog/apple-ios-news/accessibility-fixes-and-improvements-ios-81